# SAFEARRAY of COM objects

Tags: c++, com, safearray

I'm using COM library and I have interface defined in .tlh file as following:

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IMyInterface, __uuidof(IMyInterface));
```

Then I create object:

```
//1st object
IMyInterfacePtr pMyInterface1;
pMyInterface1.CreateInstance(CLSID_MyInterface);
pMyInterface1->call_some_method(BSTR("pass example text1"));

//2nd object
IMyInterfacePtr pMyInterface2;
pMyInterface2.CreateInstance(CLSID_MyInterface);
pMyInterface2->call_some_method(BSTR("pass example text2"));
```

Then I need to create SAFEARRAY of these objects:

```
SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
rgsabound[0].cElements = 2;
rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;

SAFEARRAY *pData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, rgsabound);

LONG i = 0;
SafeArrayPutElement(pData, &i, pMyInterface1);
i = 1;
SafeArrayPutElement(pData, &i, pMyInterface2);
```

But unfortunately after this array elements remains empty. Which is the proper way to fill this array of IMyInterfacePtr objects?

Thank you so much for help.

------***EDIT***------

Thanks for answers. I tried these solutions from comments, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I need to send back this array to COM by COM method. So I'm creating a new object:

```
IResponsePtr pResponse;//This is also smart com ptr
pResponse.CreateInstance(CLSID_Response);
pResponse->put_Response(pData);//safearray here
```

where `put_Response` has following signature: `(SAFEARRAY *value)`.
Unfortunately, during calling this method I'm getting the following exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76BEC54F in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEException at memory location 0x0042F144.
First-chance exception at 0x76BEC54F (KernelBase.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131533, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x72D30000).
```

Any ideas what might be wrong with this SAFEARRAY ptr?

Comment: For the exception show the callstack. Contact the developer of the COM component. Maybe your interfaces are wrong... To many possibilities... Also your edit is a new question. It has nothing to do with your original one. Mark this question as answered. Create a new question and show the new code you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the pointers. Store the pointers in the variant first and than copy the data.

```
VARIANT v;
v.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
v.punkVal = pMyInterface1;
SafeArrayPutElement(pData, &i, &v);
```

`SafeArrayPutElement` uses `AddRef` internally when it copies the variant.

Comment: You shouldn't call VariantClear in that sample code, the SafeArray must keep a reference on the interface (this reference will be removed when the SafeArray is cleared). Or call QueryInterface first to define v.punkVal (which I would recommended here, assigning pointers is dangerous)

Comment: You are right... changed my answer! The user uses a smart pointer I didn't saw this.